# Is there a technique to determine where the page fold is for any given viewport?

Tags: javascript, html, css

There are a lot of great designs that manage to scale and position their content above the page fold perfectly so that it is always at a certain position in the viewport.

Currently I would use some javascript to determine the height, but this has all the usual downsides of using Javascript for this, I use:

```
function fullScreenContainer() {

    // Set Initial Screen Dimensions

    var screenWidth = $(window).width() + "px";
    var screenHeight = $(window).height() + "px";

    $("#intro, #intro .item, #intro-video").css({
        width: screenWidth,
        height: screenHeight
    });

    $('#nav').affix({
        offset: {
            top: $('#intro').height()
        }
    });

    // Every time the window is resized...

    $(window).resize(function () {

        // Fetch Screen Dimensions

        var screenWidth = $(window).width() + "px";
        var screenHeight = $(window).height() + "px";

        // Set Slides to new Screen Dimensions

        $("#intro, #intro .item, #intro-video, #intro-video .item").css({
            width: screenWidth,
            height: screenHeight
        });

        $('#nav').affix({
            offset: {
                top: $('#intro').height()
            }
        });

    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    fullScreenContainer();
});
```

Is there a css technique that will allow me to determine how to scale and size things to match the fold perfectly no matter the browser or viewport.

I feel my Javascript solution is far too cumbersome, how do others get this right?

Comment: Discussing "page fold" can get pretty heated. It sounds like you are asking about filling the viewport; you may want to reword your question to make that point clear.

Comment: @Mathletics I wasn't quite sure how to word it, in my mind the page fold and view port are about the same thing? What is your suggestion?

Comment: "Page fold" causes rage in front-end devs; "viewport" doesn't. It's just word choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set your body, html and header height to 100%;

CSS

```css
html, body {height:100%; margin:0;}

header {height:100%; background:#aaa;}

#main {height:2000px; background:#ccc;}
```

```html
<header>
    header
</header>
<div id="main">
    main
</div>
```

Comment: Why does `#main` have a 2000px height if you're showing off percentage-based heights/widths?

Comment: I just added the 2000px to simulate the main section having a lot of content. In practice the main div does not need a height and I could have just filled that div with Lorem Ipsum.

Comment: @Calummm thanks for that, seems too easy!! I will give it a try and mark it accordingly. Cheers.

Comment: @Calummm I have a problem that when I use this in combination with additional code, the rest of the content below the main doesnt take into account the content height? See (JsFiddle)[http://jsfiddle.net/wn6uvske/] Note the footer in the middle of the content. :(